# Can't Expand inside Row

Tags: flutter

I am trying to Expand text widget that placed in Row. But I am getting error.

Code:

```
class MainContainer extends StatelessWidget
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Column (
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(

        ),
        Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
              Text("label1"),
              Expanded(child: Text("label2")) // Problem is here

            ],)

          ],),

        ),
        Container(
          child: Row(children: <Widget>[
            Text("Some Text")
          ],),
        ),
      ],    
    );
  }

}
```

Error:

> I/flutter ( 5480): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 5480): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
>   I/flutter ( 5480): RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.
>   I/flutter ( 5480): When a row is in a parent that does not provide a finite width constraint, for example if it is in a
>   I/flutter ( 5480): horizontal scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the horizontal axis. Setting a
>   I/flutter ( 5480): flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining
>   I/flutter ( 5480): space in the horizontal direction.
>   I/flutter ( 5480): These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child
>   I/flutter ( 5480): cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
>   I/flutter ( 5480): Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible
>   I/flutter ( 5480): children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
>   I/flutter ( 5480): themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and
>   I/flutter ( 5480): then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum
>   I/flutter ( 5480): constraints provided by the parent.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that your `Text` constraints are unbounded because of `Expanded` so simply you can't put an unbounded with widget inside a bounded one (or non-zero flex)

The solution is simply by putting the parent `Row` inside a flex widget (Flexible/Expanded)

```
    Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("label1"),
                Expanded(child: Text("label2")) 
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

your second row should be in `Expanded`, since you need to give it a width. And for this reason you are getting `width constraints are unbounded` error.
Your code should be

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column (
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(

        ),
        Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("label1"),
                    Expanded(child: Text("label2")) // Problem is here

                  ],),
              )

            ],),

        ),
        Container(
          child: Row(children: <Widget>[
            Text("Some Text")
          ],),
        ),
      ],
    );
}
```

Comment: "your second row should be in Expanded" I thought Row by default take all free space or I am wrong?